# Incorrect Syntax near Rows after trying to calculate Running Total on column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

***I AM ON SERVER 2008 BUT USING SSMS 2016***

I am trying to get a running total on a table and im trying to use OVER() Key word but its not working. Output should look like this:

```
Date       | Description    | PRICE | Running Total |
-----------|----------------|-------|---------------|
01/01/2018 | Apple          |  2    |       2       |
02/01/2018 | Apple          |  2    |       4       |
03/01/2018 | Apple          |  0    |       4       |
04/01/2018 | Apple          |  0    |       4       |
05/01/2018 | Apple          |  3    |       7       |
06/01/2018 | Apple          |  3    |       10      |
07/01/2018 | Apple          |  3    |       13      |
```

My code is as follows

```
WITH TOTAL AS 
            (
              SELECT 
                     DATE,
                     [Description],
                     [PRICE]
                     FROM PRODUCTS

            )
SELECT  
                    DATE,
        [Description],
        [PRICE],
        SUM([PRICE]) OVER(ORDER BY DATE ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS RUNNINGTOTAL

FROM TOTAL
```

Cant get it to work, keep getting incorrect syntax near rows error. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: The syntax is `ROWS BETWEEN` and then requires clauses for the start and end. I.e, `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` (which is the default when using `ORDER BY [Column]`).

Comment: @Larnu Frustratingly it gives me the same error

Comment: Curious that the column name that happens to be a datatype isn't quoted: `[DATE]`.

Comment: You need to check your compatibility level:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017.  You probably have it set to match an earlier version of the database.

Comment: It's also possible you are using SQL Server Management Studio 2016 but the SQL Server instance you're actually connecting to is an earlier version. Can you add to the question the output of `SELECT @@VERSION; SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = DB_NAME();`?

Comment: Embarrasingly im on 2008, Question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `CTE` or `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` :

```
SELECT [DATE], [Description], [PRICE],
       SUM([PRICE]) OVER (ORDER BY [DATE]) AS RUNNINGTOTAL
FROM PRODUCTS;
```

Comment: For some reason its gving me "Incorrect syntax near order"

Comment: @Nonagon I see nothing wrong with than SQL. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: No output, im using exactly that code, all names are correct as i have double checked

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008 does not support many of the syntax elements involving window functions and aggregates. If you look at the docs for the [`OVER Clause`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql), you can see that `ROWS` and `RANGE` were introduced in SQL Server 2012:

> ROWS | RANGE
>   
> Applies to: SQL Server 2012 (11.x) through SQL Server 2017.

Unfortunately documents like [`SUM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) don't indicate that `SUM() OVER()` was also introduced in SQL Server 2012, so Yogesh's simpler solution also won't work for you.

On SQL Server 2008 you'll have to use an older approach, like:

```
SELECT
    a.[Date],
    a.Description,
    a.Price
    RunningTotal = SUM(b.Price)
FROM
    dbo.PRODUCTS AS a
INNER JOIN
    dbo.PRODUCTS AS b
    ON a.[Date] <= b.[Date]
GROUP BY a.[Date], a.Description, a.Price
ORDER BY a.[Date];
```

Or, try using a more modern version (since the above [will **not** be fast](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals)). SQL Server 2008 is well out of support and [hits end of life in July](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/10/system-configuration/end-of-support-sql-server-2008-r2).